# Как получить статистику производительности Apache

Tags: apache

В [документации](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_status.html#enable) сказано что я могу получить доступ к статистике производительности `apache` указав путь `http://your.server.name/server-status` - что в моем случае `http://localhost/server-status`. Согласно документации я вставил этот код

```
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host localhost
</Location>
```

в главный конфигурационный файл Apache, который в моем случае называется `apache2.conf` а не `httpd.conf` так как сервер устанавливался через `apt` на `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`.

Проблема в том что делая все по инструкции из документации я не получаю страницу с той самой статистикой производительности. Вместо нее я получаю лишь ошибку в браузере `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.` и `[Thu Dec 28 03:59:04.189570 2023] [authz_core:error] [pid 6502] [client ::1:57508] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/server-status` в логах.

Вот настройки `localhost`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Что я могу сделать чтобы получить страницу с производительностью?**

Answer (score 0):

Благодарить за ответ нужно ChatGPT, ответ пишу на случай если забуду ну или может кому понадобится. В

```
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require host localhost
</Location>
```

меняем `Require host localhost` на `Require local` получится

```
<Location "/server-status">
    SetHandler server-status
    Require local
</Location>
```

Далее перезагружаем сервер `sudo service apache2 restart` и все работает.

На случай если `Require` еще не меняли и не работает отображение в браузере используйте `sudo wget http://localhost/server-status` - на выходе должна получиться та же HTML страница только под именем `server-status`.

Comment: Программисту вообще никогда не следует открывать chatGPT, пишет он в основном полную чушь.

Comment: @Глеб я бы и рад - но иногда чтобы получить ответ нужно изрядно замучить кого-то знающего)

Comment: @Глеб с каких пор конфиги апача это программирование?

Comment: @aepot, непрограммисты обычно в конфиги не лезут)